# Sorting an IQueryable result Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query which returns a IQueryable result.

```
return supplierInvoices.Union(otherInvoices.Join(orders, invoice => invoice.OrderId, order => order.Id, (invoice, order) => new { Order = order, Invoice = (invoice as IReconcilableInvoiceEntity) }))
            .GroupBy(m => m.Order)
            .Where(m => m.Any())
            .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<Order, IQueryable<IReconcilableInvoiceEntity>>(m.Key, m.Select(n => n.Invoice).AsQueryable()));
```

I need this to be sorted in descending order by `CreatedOn` column(`datetime`). I tried to use `orderbydescending(a => a.CreatedOn)` and `orderbydescending(a=> a.Key.CreatedOn)` with this query but still not giving the expected result. All help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit -
 What i have tried

```
return supplierInvoices.Union(otherInvoices.Join(orders, invoice => invoice.OrderId, order => order.Id, (invoice, order) => new { Order = order, Invoice = (invoice as IReconcilableInvoiceEntity) }))
            .GroupBy(m => m.Order)
            .Where(m => m.Any())
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Key.CreatedOn)
            .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<Order, IQueryable<IReconcilableInvoiceEntity>>(m.Key, m.Select(n => n.Invoice).AsQueryable()));
```

This doesn't sort correctly

Another try

```
return supplierInvoices.Union(otherInvoices.Join(orders, invoice => invoice.OrderId, order => order.Id, (invoice, order) => new { Order = order, Invoice = (invoice as IReconcilableInvoiceEntity) }))
            .GroupBy(m => m.Order)
            .Where(m => m.Any())
            .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<Order, IQueryable<IReconcilableInvoiceEntity>>(m.Key, m.Select(n => n.Invoice).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedOn)));
```

which gives an error.

Comment: Edit the question with the OrderByDescending that is not working so that we can see what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by two columns then you can use "**OrderByDescending(a=>a.column1)**" followed by 
"**ThenBy(a=>a.column2)**" to get desired result.